# rolling friction of a solid sphere

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

This may be a very rudimentary question. I have two spheres on a physics simulator and I need to define various parameters including rolling friction, spinning friction, inertia, color etc.

I was able to get find/tune most parameters except rolling and spinning friction.

My belief is that both frictions depend on the size of the sphere. I have spheres with varying radii. One is 0.05m and the other is 0.1m(both have mass of 0.1kg). I set the rolling friction of both spheres to be 0.03 but what exactly is the relationship between the properties of a solid sphere and sphere's friction?

EDIT:
I have spheres that are (2.0kg, 0.1m), (2.0kg, 0.075m), (1.5kg, 0.1m), (1.5kg, 0.075m) in (mass, radius) format. Can I get some sample coefficients for these assuming they are on the same surface, made with the same material.

Answer (score 2):

Rolling friction or rolling resistance of a sphere would depend on the material properties of the sphere and the surface it rolls on, the weight of the sphere and its radius. It may also depend on other parameters, such as speed, but, for your purposes, those could be neglected.

The formula for the rolling friction is similar to the formula for the sliding friction, $F=cN$, where $c$ is a coefficient of the rolling friction (typically, much smaller than the coefficient of the sliding friction for similar materials) and $N$ is the normal reaction force, which, for horizontal surfaces, would be equal to the weight of the sphere.

The coefficient of the rolling friction depends on the radius of the sphere: the smaller the radius, the greater the coefficient. For more details and formulas, you can check out this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance).

There is no "spinning friction" you need to add to the rolling friction.

Comment: In wikipedia, I found a general formula: $$F = {Nb \over r}, b = {F\cdot r \over N} $$.According to this, the rolling friction is greater when radius is greater. Which equation were you referring to when you said  smaller the radius, the greater the coefficient?

Comment: @MoneyBall $C_{rr}=\sqrt{\frac z d}$. Here, the effect of the radius is built into the coefficient. In an alternative approach, with coefficient $b$, it is not. In any case, we can say that, as the radius decreases, the role of the rolling friction increases.